# SharePoint hosted App getting Timed out

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I've  created a basic SharePoint hosted App in my machine and published it successfully.It worked all fine but, since some time the App is getting timed out and shows "Page Can't be Displayed."

Your Suggestions and thoughts will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same problem because of proper configuration. Check your configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research n trouble shooting i found out that the problem was due to my DNS Server where i had created my App Domain.

My DNS server was running in Windows Server 2008 R2 and my SharePoint was running in Windows Server 2012.

After upgrading my DNS server machine to Server 2012. Issue got Resolved.